triangle problem when two side and one angle is given to us
In a triangle $ABC$, if $\angle C = 30^\circ$, $a=47 \text{ cm}$, and $b=94 \text{ cm}$, then the triangle is
a) right angled triangle
b) right angled isosceles
c) isosceles triangle
d) obtuse angled
My attempt: I will use cosine formula as two sides and the angle between them is given, but the squares of sides seem weird. Is there any better idea to solve this problem? I tried to search for a similar question on this site, but I did not find any(there are many Indian sites where the answer is available).
$$\cos{30^\circ} = \frac{{47^2 + 94^2 - c^2}}{{2 \times 47 \times 94}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{{11045 - c^2}}{{2 \times 47 \times 94}}$$
$$47 \times 94 \times \sqrt{3} = 11045 - c^2$$
$$c^2 = 11045 - 4418 \sqrt{3} \\\text{ so } c\text{ will be }= \sqrt{11045 - 4418 \sqrt{3}} \text{....which looks messy}$$

Try factoring out $47^2$ while using the cosine rule.

Give details of your attempt

As Gwen has said, please remember that this site is not a homework-help site. It is for exchanging ideas. This means, if you do not want your question down-voted and closed, try to give some context as to why the problem is useful/interesting to others and if you are stuck at a particular point in solving, show your work to that point. The site discourages users from answering what are known as PSQs (problem-statement-questions).

@RedFive sir I have added my work, and I do not have any homework to do. Sorry for latex not working well now. I tried to write it with online word to latex convertor

In that case I will share part of my solution. Dividing all the sides by 47 (as @MathGuy suggested) and using the cosine rule, you can get the ratio of the side lengths. From there it is clear $b$ is the largest side. The rest is up to you.

$c=47\sqrt{5-2\sqrt3}$. Can you proceed now?

@MathGuy 47×2=94 a big hint sparked. So C will be nearly 57,58....and I can see that 47^2+58^2<94^2...so clearly obtuse triangle..Thanks


This is a conceptual answer, without using much geometrical formulas.
Notice that $\frac {b}{2}=a$
If we plot a circle with radius $a$, notice that $\triangle ABC$ is either obtuse or a right angle triangle, depending upon $\angle B$, until we reach this position

Here $$\cos \angle C=\frac ab = \frac 12 \implies \angle C=60°$$
As given $\angle C=30°<60°$, the triangle must be obtuse. This can be done because $\angle C$ increases with decrease in $\angle B$ upto this position

you always mesmerized me by your solution (specifically grapfs). Thank you very much for such brilliant knowledge

which book did you read for these geometric concepts. I want to know more about those books. Please let me know

I am a little bit confused with side lengths as we are given a=47,b=94 and small a will be in front of angle A so BC=47 and AC=94

@CiupTitu I had messed up naming the points, I'll upload a better gif after changing their names

@CiupTitu alright now? Regarding the books, you can use Geometry books used for helping students in Olympiads

can I know any name of olympiads book please?....now I understand the GIF properly thank you gwen
